# Get output from interactive cli commands in nodejs

Tags: node.js, command-line-interface, child-process, spawn

I want to execute a CLI command in node.js server. On CLI, when i execute this command, it asks for password, once i enter the password, it verifies and ask for the otp if the password is correct. I have the otp and password ready before calling the `spawn` function of `child_process` built-in package of node but it can handle only first prompt of password not the second prompt of otp.

```
const execute = (command: string, args: string[] = [], stdin?: string): Promise<any> => {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        const { error, stdout, stderr } = spawnSync(command, args, {
            stdio: "pipe",
            input: stdin,
            env: process.env
        });

        if (error) reject(new Error(error.message));
        if (stderr.toString().length > 0) reject(new Error(stderr.toString()));

        const output = stdout.toString().trim();
        if (output.length === 0) return;
        resolve(output);
    }
})}


await execute("op", ['account', 'add', ...accDetails], `${password}\n${otp}`);
```